# How to get current stack level

Tags: ruby, stack, stack-level

Can I get current level of stack in Ruby?

Currently I use `caller.size` which is ok, but looks not native

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`caller.size` is pretty much exactly what you want, since it is fairly standard, widely implemented, and gives you the number of frames on the stack.  It is a native function on MRI, and most other interpreters.

Comment: so there is no any `caller.stack_level`-like method?

Comment: `caller.size`?  No, there isn't an alias to give you what you want there - but it would be absolutely identical in behaviour if it did exist. :)